# How to render dynamic component in the same page based button click from different section of same page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm working on react with material-ui creating dashboard type application. In dashboard home page, there are three section, 1 for projects and 1 for project summary section and another one for notifications. I want the functionality like, when i click one of the project on project section and the project details will be rendered on the same page in the project summary section of dashboard.

i have tried `Route` of `react-router-dom`

here the project dashboard image

[image]

Here is my project code

```
 <Project  elevation={elevation1} setElevation={setElevation1} projectName="BMW S17" />
```

Single project component

```
 <Paper className={classes.pen} 
                style={{ background: 'linear-gradient(to right, #00b4db, #0083b0)' }}
                onMouseOut={ () => setElevation(1) }
                onMouseOver={ () => setElevation(5) }
                elevation={elevation}
                onClick={() => alert(`project clicked ${projectName}`)}
              >
                <Typography variant="h6" component="h3" className={classes.title}>
                    { projectName }
                </Typography>
                <Typography style={{ color: "#fff" }}>
                    Paper can be used to build surface.
                </Typography>
            </Paper>
```

Here is my routes in app.js

```
 <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Welcome} />
            <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
            <Route path="/signup" exact component={Signup} />
            <Main>
               <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
               <PrivateRoute path="/profile" component={Profile} />
            </Main>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

My private is..

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    return <Route 
     { ...rest }
     render={props => 
      localStorage.getItem('authToken') ? (
        <Component { ...props } />
      ) : (
          <Redirect 
            to={{ 
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: props.location }
          }} />
       )
      }
     /> 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AS I understood you want to implement a project details based on the project name.

For this kind of implementation , you can use TABS(https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/) rather than routes . To align vertical , you can use vertical section in tabs component. Route should be used , when you want to redirect to some other page .

Answer (score 0):

**Sidebar** sample application in reactjs using `react-router-dom`
[image: sample]

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import "./styles.css";
import Header from "./Header";
const Home = () => (
  <div className="rightside">
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
  </div>
);
const About = () => (
  <div className="rightside">
    <h1>About Page</h1>
  </div>
);
const Product = () => (
  <div className="rightside">
    <h1>Product Page</h1>
  </div>
);
const Contact = () => (
  <div className="rightside">
    <h1>Contact Page</h1>
  </div>
);
const headerStyle = {
  padding: 10,
  background: "darkcyan"
};
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <header style={headerStyle}>Header</header>
    <div className="main">
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/product" component={Product} />
        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Header.js

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";
export default function Header() {
  return (
    <div className="leftside">
      <ul>
        <li><NavLink to="/home">Home</NavLink></li>
        <li><NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink></li>
        <li><NavLink to="/product">Product</NavLink></li>
        <li><NavLink to="/contact">Contact</NavLink></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

styles.css

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.main {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}
.leftside {
  background: darkgrey;
}
.rightside {
}
.leftside ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.leftside ul li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.leftside ul li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: black;
  margin: 1px 0px;
}
.leftside ul li:hover {
  background: darkcyan;
  color: white;
}
```